# htaccess redirect for unordered links

Tags: .htaccess

I have an URL:

```
mysite.com/a/b,c,d,e,f
```

And the condition that works correctly:

```
RewriteRule ^a/b,c,d,e,f/([0-9]+)(/?)$ /f/cat=a,b,c,d,e,f [L]
RewriteRule ^a/b,c,d,e,f(/?)+$ /f/cat=a,b,c,d,e,f [L]
```

Is there a rule that will work even if there is a link like

```
mysite.com/a/c,b,e,f,d   ->   /f/cat=a,b,c,d,e,f
mysite.com/a/e,f,d,b,c   ->   /f/cat=a,b,c,d,e,f
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only feasible if the parts in question are distinguishable, i.e. you can tell the URL query string element `a` from not `a` and `b` from not `b`, etc.

To get the idea ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pdPox/1)):

```
(a)/(?=.*(b))(?=.*(c))(?=.*(d))(?=.*(e))(?=.*(f)).,.,.,.,.(/?)
```

If there is overlap, e.g. the parts are actually just a bunch of numbers, this will not fly.